# What material will expand after being compressed?

Tags: materials-design, metamaterials

The theory of elasticity is essential in engineering. The most basic law is that any piece becomes smaller if one compresses it. My question is:

How can a piece of material expand (some minutes, hours, or days) after being compressed?

It is against our intuition. A related topic is the development of (meta)material with negative Poisson's ratio, which is also counterintuitive.

I suppose such material is possible, for example, a linear spring (as harmonic oscillator) with a very long period (you press it today, it expands tomorrow). I am wondering whether there is subfield developing such unusual material.

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to know the potential energy surface (PES) of the system. Assuming the system is in equilibrium before applying the deformation, any modification will take it to a non-equilibrium state. Depending on in which points of the PES the system is/go and the amount of strain/stress accumulated during the compression, the tendency is to free the extra energy and came back to equilibrium.

Comment: Thank you very much! Are there physical implementation of such materials (could be informed by external force, as I understand)?

Comment: It's worth adding that the relaxation time to return to equilibrium (the original shape) can vary dramatically if the underlying dynamics are slow.